# express 4 setup static from required module fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an odd error, I had the app working fine, but then as the `app.js` was getting pretty bloated so we split out certain logic to other files and for some reason the static file handler now seems to stop routes working.

```
Error: Forbidden
   at SendStream.error (C:\Code\Web\testing\_packages\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\lib\send.js:228:16)
   at SendStream.pipe (C:\Code\Web\testing\_packages\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\lib\send.js:413:19)
   at staticMiddleware (C:\Code\Web\testing\_packages\node_modules\express\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:92:12)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Code\Web\testing\_packages\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:76:5)
   at trim_prefix (C:\Code\Web\testing\_packages\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:263:13)
   at C:\Code\Web\testing\_packages\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:230:9
   at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Code\Web\testing\_packages\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:305:12)
   at C:\Code\Web\testing\_packages\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:221:12
   at Function.match_layer (C:\Code\Web\testing\_packages\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:288:3)
   at next (C:\Code\Web\testing\_packages\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:182:10)
```

There is the error, the app file used to call:
`app.use(express.static("{0}/public".format(__dirname)));`

However now because its loaded from another file we have done `app.set("rootdir", __dirname)` in the `app.js` file then in the other module we do:

`app.use(express.static("{0}/public".format(app.get("rootdir"))));`

Everything runs fine but when I load up a route it blows up with the error, whereas it used to work. I have done console.log to confirm the `rootdir` and it is fine, also have done the same thing in `app.js` and it is EXACTLY the same.

So is there any known issues around this?

Comment: Are you using some code/module that mutates `String.prototype`? There is no native `String.prototype.format`. You're better off using something like `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));`

Comment: oh yes sorry there is a custom string library used which enhances the string prototype.